# Apply the CSS if the element doesn't have this parent class

Tags: jquery, css

How can I only apply the CSS if the element doesn't have this parent class "menu-item-has-children". Is it possible with CSS or JQuery?

```
.menu-item-has-children .sub-menu {
   width: 147px!important;
   right: -45px
}
```

Comment: That's how it was structured by default and I can't touch it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`:not` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) but be aware that this will apply to *any* `.sub-menu` that is not a child of that particular class.

```css
:not(.menu-item-has-children) .sub-menu {
  width: 147px!important;
  right: -45px
}
```

Comment: An element with a parent having that class is also a descendant of, eg, `body` which matches the `:not(...)` part

Comment: Yes, that is why it should be used carefully

Comment: I mean it'll simply apply the width and margin even if one/some of the parent has that class.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it doesn't work on my end.